# IllegalMonitorStateException in thread

Tags: java, wait, synchronized

i want to use synchronized  in Vector run in thread

i try tow methode one for wait and other for notfiy

i want to call the notify method from static class 
this my thread code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;


public class TSend extends Thread {

     Vector<String> File_Message=new Vector<String>();


        public void save_out_putMessage(String out_Msg){

             synchronized(this.File_Message){
       this.File_Message.add(out_Msg);
       this.File_Message.notify();

        }

        }


public synchronized String GetMessage() throws InterruptedException{
        String message;
        while(File_Message.size()==0){
            this.File_Message.wait();
        }

         message = File_Message.get(0);
        File_Message.removeElementAt(0);
        return message;
}


public  synchronized void Recepteur_de_Message (String message){

    /*
     * Pour savgarde tout les message des client dans un vecteur Message . 
     * 
      */
    File_Message.add(message);

    notify();

}


@Override
public void run(){
    try{
          String Message ;
          while(true){
                str =GetMessage();  
          }
    }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and i try to do this :

```
 synchronized(F){
     while(F.size()==0) {
         F.wait();
     }

     Message= new String(F.get(0));
     F.removeElementAt(0);
 }
```

but i have this excption wan i try to run

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at TSend.GetMessage(TSend.java:39)
    at TSend.run(TSend.java:78)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
this.File_Message.wait();
```

within some thread that does not own the monitor on the referenced object. You do this in a `synchronized` method. In a `synchronized` method, the monitor is acquired on `this` object.

It's not obvious to me why you are trying to call `wait()` on that object, but you'll need to own its monitor at that point if you want to do it.

Go through the [tutorial on `synchronized` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) and the javadoc of [`Object#wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29).